# Flawed rendering of web fonts on Chrome under Windows 7

Tags: google-chrome, windows-7, webfonts

When using Google Web Fonts on Chrome under windows 7, the fonts seem to render incorrectly, while on a Mac OSX (on Chrome, Safari and Firefox) it looks fine. Is there a way to prevent this via CSS or HTML?

The site introducing this behavior can be found [here](http://gasloggr.com) (it might take a while until it loads).

Here's a snapshot showing this:

[image: font aliasing issue]

Comment: It looks nothing like your screenshot to me. Go to Control Panel, search for ClearType and see if you have that disabled.

Comment: looks like non-native screen resolution

Comment: cleartype is enabled. font looks great on ie9 on the same box and same display.

Comment: @gorelative, you wrote it looks like crap on IE9, then that it looks great on ie9. Two different browsers? :-)

Comment: I did, was a typo i updated the question. Chrome is the only one that makes things look bad.

Comment: Looks fine on my machine (Win 7/Chrome Version 23.0.1271.64 m)

Comment: Same here, Chrome 22.0.1229.94 Windows 8 RP (haven't gotten around to updating to the release).

Comment: please state the specific font you're using. some fonts may reveal aliasing issues while others won't.

Comment: yeah its fixed now randomly.. odd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright so this has to do with the way Chrome renders fonts in windows. There is a tool you can use called MacType which changes the rendering engine that windows uses to render fonts.

You can download it here: https://code.google.com/p/mactype/

From everything that i have researched, with google web fonts on windows there currently does not exist a way to fix this issue.

Its simply by design how it works.

You can follow the issue on Chromiums Google Code site..
https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=137692

#### heres a snip from the above link that goes in to more detail

> As I understand it: the main problem is the fact that Chrome continues
> to use the old Windows GDI for rendering fonts, and it looks poor. All
> other modern browsers (except Opera) have switched to using
> DirectWrite on Windows, resulting in much better font rendering,
> leaving Chrome lagging.
>
> If you look back at older versions of IE and Firefox you'll see their
> font rendering a few years ago looked exactly the same as Chrome's
> does today on Windows. People just didn't notice as much back then as
> nobody was using web fonts; when you're using Arial, Verdana etc they
> look OK because those fonts have been carefully designed and hinted to
> work well with the GDI engine. Most web fonts have not.

#### for developers, one work around is to put SVG first, doubt this is proper though

```
-before--------------

@font-face {
font-family: 'chunk-webfont';
src: url('../../includes/fonts/chunk-webfont.eot');
src: url('../../includes/fonts/chunk-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('eot'),
url('../../includes/fonts/chunk-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
url('../../includes/fonts/chunk-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
url('../../includes/fonts/chunk-webfont.svg') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
}


-after--------------

@font-face {
font-family: 'chunk-webfont';
src: url('../../includes/fonts/chunk-webfont.eot');
src: url('../../includes/fonts/chunk-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('eot'),
url('../../includes/fonts/chunk-webfont.svg') format('svg'),
url('../../includes/fonts/chunk-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
url('../../includes/fonts/chunk-webfont.ttf') format('truetype');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found some solution   [here](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=336476#c30)  and it works for me

Have added a temporary fix with the following code...

```
$('body')
  .delay(500)
  .queue( 
    function(next){ 
        $(this).css('padding-right', '1px'); 
    }
  );
```